# Are users given back rep if another person compromises their account and uses it to post spam?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, spam

What if some person has access to someone else's Stack Exchange account (compromised credentials, open laptop, etc.) and goes ahead and posts something useless or even offensive garnering multiple downvotes and thereby negatively affecting that person's reputation?

Can the original user be awarded his rep back on an appeal/request? This is, of course, keeping in mind the question asked is not a "bad" question; mainly spam.

Comment: I suspect using the contact us link, and giving a detailed explanation of what happened would be a good start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; this is already in place:

- When the question/answer is deleted, the reputation lost (or gained) with it will be reversed.
- ♦ moderators can clear spam flags if there are signs the user's account has been compromised. That way, the posts will stay deleted but the -100 reputation penalty (and the blocking of further posts) will be revoked.